# Making a DIV expand a View (ie showing another DIV)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs in the image below.  Each **div** is a link that now points to '**#**'.  How can I make it so that when I click a **div** the dotted line at the bottom expands to show another **div**.

Each "div link" has a different View (just a div) that it shows.

[image: Image of Div Links]

Here's the code for the DIVs:

```
<div id="tour"> 
   <div id="link" onclick="location.href='#';"  >               
      <img src="images/icn1.png" alt="" />
      <h2>Pitch</h2>
      <p> blah blah blah balh blah blah blah blah balh blah blah blah blah balh <p>
    </div>

    <div id="link" onclick="location.href='#';" >
       <img src="images/icn2.png" alt="" />   
       <h2>Publish</h2>
       <p> blah blah blah balh blah blah blah blah balh blah blah blah blah balh <p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Would using jQuery Tabs be a good solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes. I'm playing with .show and .hide but I feel like the code is too cumbersome.  I figured there must be an easier method.  I should probably post that.

Comment: Yes, you should. And in response to your edit, I'd argue that jQuery Tabs is totally unnecessary if you have any desire to actually lean jQuery. What you're trying to accomplish is not difficult, so I think a plugin is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the jQuery UI Tab. Each of your DIVs will be a Tab, and the View will be the Tab's Content. Here's a link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#collapsible

Comment: This might actually be the simplest method.  Are the tabs customizable so that I can use what I already have?

Comment: I believe they are. You can put any content inside the tabs. Each Tab is created by a LI tag and you can put anything inside. The CSS is customizable, too.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into the jQuery `.show()` function here: http://api.jquery.com/show/

On `document.ready()` you can hide the `div` that you later want to display. And then you can bind a `click` function to the div like this:

```
$(".link").click(function () {
    $("#someDiv").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('yourdivClass/IDhere').click(function(){
  $('divyouwanttoopen/close').toggle();
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

On click of each of the div in top, You can use $('div-element-to-show').show () function to show.

See documentation for `.show()' **[here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**

**Note:** HTML tag -> ID attribute should be unique across a html docuement, in you example you seem to use same ID (`<div id="link" onclick="location.href='#';"  >`) for both the div's.

Check the .animate **[here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**, if you want to show the below div with some style like slide,fade, e.t.c

Step 1. Add a click listener for `<div id="link" onclick="location.href='#';"  >` as below,

```
$('#link').click ( function () { 
      //add code here to show the div
});
```

Step 2: Use .show to show the div content below the dotted section.

Step 3: In case if you have to show only one div content below, Make sure to use .hide() function to hide the currently displaying div before showing the new content. You can check the .hide() documentation **[here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

Try these and Let me know if you need some clarifications.